# QT Get request parsing JSON

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a `GET request` in order to authenticate a user. Here is my code to do that:

```
void MainWindow::on_loginButton_clicked()
{
    QString email = "test";
    QString password = "test";

    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
             this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url("http://url.com/api.php?action=authenticate_user&email=" + email + "&password" + password);
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void MainWindow::serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

        QStringList propertyNames;
        QStringList propertyKeys;

        QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();

        qDebug() << strReply;

        QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());

        QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();

        QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["status"].toArray();

        qDebug() << jsonObject["status"].toString();

        foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray)
        {
            QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
            qDebug() << value.toString();
        }

    } else {
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
    }

    delete reply;
}
```

But for some reason `qDebug() << strReply;` just outputs:

```
""Missing argument""
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo. Correcting the typo fixes the issue. Neither the question nor the answer will be useful for anyone else. If anything, the attempted solution has safety-related problems and should not serve as reference material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server tells you that your request is missing an argument. Have a detailed look at the request and double-check it.

```
QUrl url("http://url.com/api.php?action=authenticate_user&email=" + email + "&password" + password);
```

Seems to me that the URL is wrong, shouldn't it say `"&password=" + ...` there?

Comment: If i copy the exact same `URL` in the browser it returns a JSON, so that can not be the problem i think

Comment: The exact same URL? so an url that contains ...&email=foo@example.com&passwordMySecrectPassword works in a browser?